# Knight captures queen and rook in minimum moves

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

You are given a chess board containing a knight, rook and queen. You should determine the minimal number of moves the knight needs to capture both the rook and the queen, assuming neither of them moves. You may capture them in either order - rook first or queen first.

[Complete problem statement](http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=2915&rd=5853).

In this task, can it be proven that path from the knight to the rook plus the path from the rook to the queen is equal/smaller/bigger than the path from the knight to the queen plus the path from the queen to the rook? Or I must compute them both and take the minimum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the starting positions are all arbitrary, the Queen and Rook could theoretically be swapped to generate an alternate version of the same problem. Thus, you can't assume one way is shorter than the other by default, you have to calculate them both. It doesn't matter which one is which, but all 3 distances are relevant.

The following is only relevant if you want to implement an intelligent algorithm instead of a breadth search.

Note that there are a total of 4 possible paths (K is Knight, R is Rook, Q is queen):

```
1. K -> R -> Q
2. K -> Q -> R
3. K -> R -> K -> Q
4. K -> Q -> K -> R
```

You need the minimum between these 4. So if you computed distances

```
a = K -> Q
b = K -> R
c = R -> Q
```

then you're looking for the minimum between `a+c`, `b+c`, `2*a+b` and `2*b+a`.
If you calculate your distance in a sufficiently robust way, the paths 3 and 4 become obsolete because they have a greater or the same length as 1 and 2, respectively. However, if you're unsure, you can use them to confirm the results. If 3 or 4 is the shortest path, it has to be exactly as long as 1 or 2 if your algorithm works correctly.

Comment: The last two are the same as the first two. If you compute `K -> Q -> R` is is the same as `K -> R -> K -> Q`.

Comment: Also depending on how you determine the distance, paths 3 and 4 are obsolete because `R -> Q` and `R -> K -> Q` would be identical (in terms of distance) in the case where the shortest path contains the Knight's starting position. So considering all paths is really just a method to confirm your calculations.

Comment: @J.M: That's generally not true. Those 2 are only the same if the distance from Queen to Rook is twice the distance from Knight to Rook (in the terms from above, `c = 2*b`). And this is not necessarily (and actually usually not) the case. Actually, it's only true if both Queen and Rook have the same distance from the Knight and the shortest path between the two contains the Knight's starting position.

Comment: So only minimum of `a+c` and `b+c` is not enough? So i must consider the other two too?

Comment: @J.M: That depends on your algorithm to determine distance. If it's robust, each one out of `a`, `b` and `c` are always lower than or equal to twice the others. But the paths might differ. Basically, the last 2 paths are only good solutions if the Knight is between the Queen and Rook in such a way that there is no shorter path between the two except through his position. But in this case, the paths 1 and 3 (as well as 2 and 4) have the same length, so you don't *really* need them (but you can use them to check the result). That's what I was trying to say in my first comment...

Comment: What do you mean by `robust` algorithm? I will use breadth first search to compute the minimum distance. What other algorithm can be used?

Comment: `R -> K -> Q` cannot possibly be shorter than `R -> Q`. The former is generally meaningless. You are just arbitrarily inserting an arbitrary and unneeded waypoint into an otherwise usable path.

Comment: @J.M: Robustness is only relevant for strategic search algorithms, for a breadth search, it's irrelevant. Algorithms that construct paths with a specific strategic approach are usually much faster but also much more complicated than breadth searches and can sometimes fail if they encounter the wrong initial conditions (getting caught in loops, for example). `robust` means the algorithms is more resistant to such problems. Unless you want to try a faster approach, you can ignore the additional paths.

Comment: Thanks for the deep explanation :)

Comment: @n.m.: As I said, this is for checking the search algorithm. Some "smart" algorithms might get lost and calculate inaccurate results, which you can catch by checking whether or not the composite path is shorter than the direct one. If it's shorter, your algorithm failed. On a side note, the path is usually not unique, so there are several shortest paths. If speed is a concern, building the shortest path out of the two halves after a computationally cheap check is faster than running the entire algorithm again to get the complete path.

Comment: By the way, another trivial reason why I've mentioned these 2 paths is the fact that they're being hinted at in the detailed problem description. This might confuse people, hence my explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You must compute the minimum of knight to rook and knight to queen.

The path from queen to rook is equal to the path from rook to queen, so you only need to compute that one way.